# Statement inside if or else if never executes Android

Tags: android

I have a method that returns bitmap object , based on parameter . 
The if condition doesn't executes , I don't know whats exactly the problem , I am trying to print Log statement inside the if condition which is not working

```
public static Bitmap getWesternZodiacIcon(Context context,String westernZodiacSign)throws Exception{

      //Context context = null;

      Bitmap westernZodiacIcon = null;   

      if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Aries")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_aries);
        Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", "westernZodiacSign");
    }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Taurus")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_taurus);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
    }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Gemini")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_gemini);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Cancer")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_cancer);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Leo")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_lion);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Virgo")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_virgin);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Libra")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_scales);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Scorpio")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_scorpion);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Sagittarius")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_sagittarius);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Capricorn")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_capricor);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Aquarius")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_aquarius);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Pisces")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_pisces);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }

      return westernZodiacIcon;
  }
```

Comment: computers dont use magic, westernZodiacSign either doesnt equal any of those things or your method is never called. Have you tried putting a `Log.v("westernZodiacSign", westernZodiacSign);` before the if tests?

Comment: check Case of character, if you not sure you can use ignoreCase or first change to toLowerCase and then check that

Comment: Use debugger, also you might want to replace equals with equalsIgnoreCase.

Comment: yes it works , if I put the Log statement before the IF condition , then I can get the value inside westernZodiacSign, but inside the IF or ELSE IF,it doesn't works

Comment: The code throws a `NullPointerException` since context is `null`. You seem to ignore the exception in the calling code. This explains why the log statements are not reached.

Comment: can you show us value of `westernZodiacSign`?

Comment: westernZodiacSign = Aries

Comment: change `log` line with `westernZodiacIcon` line and run again

Comment: @ Pang ----- yes ,the Log prints

Comment: @karthik then your condition is right. So what is the problem?

Comment: if you have this function in try catch statement I think problem is context that is null and because catch you app don't crash.

Comment: @ Shayan pourvatan ----- westernZodiacIcon  returns null

Comment: Maybe `Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", "westernZodiacSign");` should be `Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);` (without double quotes for `westernZodiacSign`) in your first `if`?

Comment: I, edited code for the Context null problem

Comment: @karthik where is context declared or initialized? How is context passed a param to the function?

Comment: @ Raghunandan---tempWesternZodiacIcon=BirthdayCalculation.getWesternZodiacIcon(this,westernZodiacSign);
     westernZodiacIcon=BirthdayCalculation.convertToZodiacByte(tempContactImage);

Comment: @karthik edit your post and post the full code. Likely `this` does not refer to activity context

Comment: Are you sure that there are no whitespaces before or after `"Aries"` in `westernZodiacSign`? Try logging like this: `Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", "[" + westernZodiacSign + "]");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider *all* cases. Add another else:

```
...
else if (westernZodiacSign.equals("Pisces")) {
          westernZodiacIcon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.zodiac_pisces);
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", westernZodiacSign);
        }
else {
          Log.v("westernZodiacIcon", "The null hypothesis for astrology is...");                  
}
```

Plus an exception might be thrown as indicated in the method signature, so try catching it and logging as well.